Import Gerbers into Altium - Plane shapes wrong
I'm trying to convert some gerbers into an Altium PCB file using Camtastic and everything imports fine for the most part but the annoying thing is planes will import as stacked horizontal 1 mil tracks instead of a solid plane shape. Short of tediously deleting all these lines and attempting to remake all the plane shapes does anyone have any advice on a method to have it recognize plane shapes from gerber data? In camtastic it seems to recognize it as a plane shape which is why it's so frustrating that it is doing this.

